# Flutter App Crashes on startup, Firebase Issue

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing an issue while running my flutter app on android devices. App is crashing on startup.

Here is the stack trace.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA8Fb.png

> √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208): Process: com.a2meeamanora.parentsapp, PID: 31208
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;Lcom/google/firebase/iid/Metadata;Lcom/google/firebase/platforminfo/UserAgentPublisher;Lcom/google/firebase/heartbeatinfo/HeartBeatInfo;Lcom/google/firebase/installations/FirebaseInstallationsApi;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/GmsRpc; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc' appears in /data/app/com.a2meeamanora.parentsapp-QBK-qAIbuN0wwRvjbwIR2A==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.TopicsSubscriber.createInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:1)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:12)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0$FirebaseMessagingRegistrar(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:25)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar$$Lambda$0.create(Unknown Source:0)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.doInitializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:291)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:281)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:584)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:303)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2064)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2039)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6487)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6039)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1774)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6759)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
> E/AndroidRuntime(31208):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)

Comment: Did you add your sha key in firebase and add the json file in your project?

Comment: @KaushikChandru yes, I have already added.